# VBA Run-time Error Opening Files in a Folder

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to open all files in a specified folder. This is the code I have (I have put Path and FolderName as generic but they work and the code gets the correct path and correct folder  name when I run it):

'''

```
Dim FolderName As String, FSOLibrary As Object, FSOFolder As Object, FSOFile As Object

FolderName = Path
'set all the references to the FSO Library
Set FSOLibrary = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set FSOFolder = FSOLibrary.GetFolder(FolderName)

Set FSOFile = FSOFolder.Files

For Each FSOFile In FSOFile
currentfile = FSOFile.Name
Workbooks.Open FSOFile.currentfile
```

'''

When I execute the code I get run time error,  object doesn't support this property or method. However the currentfile always has the correct filepath and name. Unsure why it is unable to open the files.

Comment: Two things I've noticed, I believe when using For Each in VBA you need to first create a variable of type Variant. Also, you've written

Comment: You are using FSOFile twice as a variable.

Comment: And the strange thing (at least for me) is that `For Each FSOFile In FSOFile` is working as long as you do not use early binding.

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass to `Workbooks.Open` a full file name, in your case I assume it is

```
Workbooks.Open Path & "\" & currentfile
```

An improved version of your code would look like

```
Dim FolderName As String, FSOLibrary As Object, FSOFolder As Object, FSOFile As Object, FSOFiles As Object
    
FolderName = Path
'set all the references to the FSO Library
Set FSOLibrary = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set FSOFolder = FSOLibrary.GetFolder(FolderName)
    
Set FSOFiles = FSOFolder.Files

For Each FSOFile In FSOFiles
    Workbooks.Open FSOFile.Path & "\" & FSOFile.Name
    'Debug.Print FSOFile.Path & "\" & FSOFile.Name
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

Two things I've noticed, I believe when using For Each in VBA you need to first create a variable of type Variant. Also, you've written `For Each FSOFile in FSOFile` which would be invalid anyway because you're trying to loop a variable through itself...

Try changing the bottom part of your code to this:

```
Set FSOFiles = FSOFolder.Files

Dim FSOFile as Variant

For Each FSOFile in FSOFiles
currentfile = FSOFile.Name
Workbooks.Open FSOFile.currentfile
```

Comment: Does the FSOFile object have a `currentfile` member? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/file-object

Comment: Good question, I copied the OP's code for that piece as I assumed it must have, but I guess it might not.

Comment: Unfortunately the same error occurs, and yes it does.

Answer (score 0):

Unless there's a specific reason you want to use the FileSystemObject, I find that using Dir is faster and easier:

```
Sub tgr()
    
    Dim sFolderPath As String
    Dim sFileName As String
    
    sFolderPath = "C:\Temp\SO\"
    If Right(sFolderPath, 1) <> "\" Then sFolderPath = sFolderPath & "\"    'Just ensuring sFolderPath ends with a \
    
    sFileName = Dir(sFolderPath & "*.xls*") 'The "*.xls*" will ensure that only Excel files are found
    
    'Begin loop, sFileName will only be populated if a file matching the Dir filter was found
    Do While Len(sFileName) > 0
        
        'Open the file
        With Workbooks.Open(sFolderPath & sFileName)
            'Do stuff with the opened file
            MsgBox .Worksheets(1).Range("A1").Value
            
            .Close SaveChanges:=False    'Close the file when done with it, choose to save changes or not
        End With
        
        sFileName = Dir()   'Advance sFileName to the next file matching the previously set Dir filter
    Loop    'Close loop
    
End Sub
```